# Add or remove element in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'd like to add an object to an array if it does not already exists and delete it if it already exists in the array. 
I succeed for adding the first item, but it does not work if I add an other object in the array. I can delete the first item. There is a bug, i don't know why.

Here is my code :

```
function checkAmi(pseudo, id) {
    var info = ({
        pseudo: pseudo,
        id: id
    });
    if (amisNotifies.length > 0) {
        // iterate over each element in the array
        for (var i = 0; i < amisNotifies.length; i++) {
            console.log(angular.toJson(amisNotifies[i].pseudo));
            // look for the entry with a matching `code` value
            if (amisNotifies[i].pseudo === pseudo) {
                amisNotifies.removeValue('pseudo', pseudo);
                $("#checkAmi" + id).addClass("fa-circle-o");
                $("#checkAmi" + id).removeClass("fa-check-circle-o");
            } else {
                amisNotifies.push(info);
                $("#checkAmi" + id).removeClass("fa-circle-o");
                $("#checkAmi" + id).addClass("fa-check-circle-o");
            }
        }
    } else {
        amisNotifies.push(info);
        $("#checkAmi" + id).removeClass("fa-circle-o");
        $("#checkAmi" + id).addClass("fa-check-circle-o");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `amisNotifies`? What is `removeValue`?

Comment: amisNotifies = []; removeValue is a function that remove the object value pseudo

Comment: There is no function called `removeValue` in standard JS arrays.

Comment: I made it, i say it works in the subject, i succeed add the first and remove it

Comment: If you ask for help and don't show all the relevant code, well, then it's impossible to help you.

Comment: You're looping from 0...length-1.  If you remove an item at index `i`, then the item at `i+1` moves into position `i` so gets skipped when the loop is reentered.  You can solve this by iterating from length-1 to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are wrongly checking the duplication, by just comparing every items with **pseudo**. you need to loop through all the items to see if it matches any, then perform add/remove based on matching. following code will work for you.

```
function checkAmi(pseudo, id) {
    var info = ({
        pseudo: pseudo,
        id: id
    });
    var getIndexOf = function (psdu) {
        for (var i = 0; i < amisNotifies.length; i++) {
            if (amisNotifies[i].pseudo === psdu) {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    };

    if (amisNotifies.length > 0) {
        var index = getIndexOf(pseudo);
        if (index > -1) {
            //so already exists. now remove it.
            Array.prototype.splice.call(amisNotifies, index, 1);
            $("#checkAmi" + id).addClass("fa-circle-o");
            $("#checkAmi" + id).removeClass("fa-check-circle-o");
        }
        else {
            //does not exist, now add it
            amisNotifies.push(info);
            $("#checkAmi" + id).removeClass("fa-circle-o");
            $("#checkAmi" + id).addClass("fa-check-circle-o");
        }

    } else {
        amisNotifies.push(info);
        $("#checkAmi" + id).removeClass("fa-circle-o");
        $("#checkAmi" + id).addClass("fa-check-circle-o");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You can do this

```
const addOrRemove = (array, item) => {
  const exists = array.includes(item)

  if (exists) {
    return array.filter((c) => { return c !== item })
  } else {
    const result = array
    result.push(item)
    return result
  }
}
```

Comment: There's a pretty subtle flaw in this answer, which may or may not be an issue depending on the use case. In the positive branch you are returning a brand new array. However, in the negative branch you are mutating the existing array and returning that. Best practice would be to pick a strategy and be consistent. If you're being purely functional about it, then you would avoid mutation.

Answer (score 11):

TESTED

this is another simple solution:

```
var newItem = "NEW_ITEM_TO_ARRAY";
var array = ["OLD_ITEM_1", "OLD_ITEM_2"];
array.indexOf(newItem) === -1 ? array.push(newItem) : array.splice(array.indexOf(newItem), 1);

console.log(array)
```

indexOf will return -1 if it's not found, meaning that if it doesn't exist, you will add.. for more Info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

else if it is found, meaning that it exists, you will delete it with splice, the first parameter is the index and the second is how many elements you will delete: for more info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 2):

The builtin `pop` and `shift` methods remove from either end.

If you want to remove an element in the middle of an array you can use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) thus

```
function removeElementAtIndex(arr, i) {
  Array.prototype.splice.call(arr, i, 1);
}
```

---

How to tell whether an element is **in** an array depends on what you mean by "in".

`indexOf` is pretty good, but there's a corner case: `[NaN].indexOf(NaN)` is `-1` because `NaN !== NaN`.

Assuming you're not worried about `NaN`, you could do

```
function togglePresent(arr, el) {
  var idx = arr.indexOf(el);
  if (idx >= 0) {
    arr.splice(idx, 1);
  } else {
    arr.push(el);
  }
}
```

and if you do care, you can try a different strategy to recompute `idx` when `isNaN(el)`.

Note: this only removes one instance of `el` in `arr`.

Comment: But I put console.log to test it, it goes until the push of the loop for. It doesnt push the new info

Comment: @guillaumekotarba, How are you logging it?  When you pass an object to `console.log` instead of a string it may delay converting it to a string which means the log message may not represent the state of the message at the time `console.log` was called.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic does not seem to be correct - say you have 2 items in amiNotifies and you want to add a third new value - the first time the for loop runs(i=0), it will add the item(pseudo), the second time(i = 1) it will remove the added item(pseudo) and ultimately the new item will not be added, you should rework around the logic of adding and removing based on existence in amiNotifies.

You should probably use the **splice** operation to remove values from amiNotifies as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use. Typescript, but strip type hinting to use in JS.

```
export function addOrRemove<T>(source: T[], candidate: T, comparator?: (a: T, b: T) => boolean): T[] {
  const c = comparator || ((a, b) => a == b)
  const e = source.find(i => c(i, candidate))
  return e ? source.filter(i => !c(i, candidate)) : [...source, candidate]
}
```

It will immutably toggle an array element (remove if it's present, add if not). An optional comparator function as the last argument can be used to compare non-scalar values, such as an object.

Answer (score 0):

In one of vue-3 projects, I did this:

```
<script>
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const itemsSelected = ref([]);

    const addOrRemoveItem = (itemId) => {
      const exists = itemsSelected.value.includes(itemId);

      if (exists) {
        itemsSelected.value = itemsSelected.value.filter((id) => id !== itemId);
      } else {
        itemsSelected.value.push(itemId);
      }
    };

    return { addOrRemoveItem };
  },
});
</script>
```